# Sync Exchange calendar with iPhone

Tags: iphone, calendar, exchange-activesync

I've had a work Exchange email account on my iPhone for over a year and recently wanted to sync the calendar as well.

I go into account settings on my iPhone, turn on Calendar syncing and opt to keep my local iPhone calendar. The calendar events (and the actual additional calendar) never appear, any ideas?

We use Outlook 2003 and Kerio Mailserver, however this setup works fine with my iPad (where I have the additional calendar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my server name to one of its aliases and it refreshed the account and started working: it created a new Exchange calendar and synced the appointments.

I can only conclude that the different aliases map to different ports (I need to speak to our systems admin to confirm), though a colleague was using my "old" alias and his iPhone was syncing fine.

Comment: Make sure you use the actual A record address of the mailserver and not a CNAME.  We've had trouble with various Mac apps not working properly with CNAMEs, but they do work with the original A records.  Doesn't make any sense, but there it is.  :-)

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch - Thanks, I'll check with our systems admin about that.